# jenkins pipline rsync some files error

Tags: git, jenkins, rsync

When i use jenkins pipline to checkout from gitlab and rsync to remote host , it was error.But in the same machine different directory checkout and rsync to remote host no problem。And in the same machine same directory rsync to another remote host no problem.

Here is my rsync command:

```
rsync -avn --delete '-e ssh -p 666' ./dist/ root@x.x.x.x:/data/foweb/dist/
```

My pipline script:

```
node {

stage('CheckOut') {
  checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '**']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'a2cc73a7-b0c8-4497-9083-47ef78a03bc4', url: 'git@gitlab.foschool.cn:front/foweb.git']]])
}

stage('Build') {
   sh '''
   cnpm install
   npm run build
   '''
}

stage('Deploy Test'){
   sh '''
   rsync -av --delete '-e ssh -p 666' ./dist/  root@x.x.x.x:/data/www/foweb/
   '''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever Jenkins and ssh is failing, while the ssh command (here through `rsync -e`) is working locally, you need to check the user running Jenkins.

If that user is not the same as the local one (which is running ssh successfully), that means the `~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` keys are not visible for Jenkins.
You need to report those keys to the `~user/.ssh` running Jenkins (or, better, to create dedicated keys for Jenkins)